# The sip module implements API v11.0 to v11.2 but the PyQt5.QtCore module requires API v11.3

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt4, qtcore

I have a problem with this error. For the record, I'm using PyQt4. Thanks for any help!

```
 (C:\Users\ewasn\Anaconda2) C:\Users\ewasn\Desktop\DataShift>python data_inconsistency_api.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "data_inconsistency_api.py", line 9, in <module>
    from multivariate_outliers import MultivariateOutliers
  File "C:\Users\ewasn\Desktop\DataShift\multivariate_outliers.py", line 8, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "C:\Users\ewasn\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 114, in <module>
    _backend_mod, new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()
  File "C:\Users\ewasn\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\__init__.py", line 32, in pylab_setup
    globals(),locals(),[backend_name],0)
  File "C:\Users\ewasn\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt5agg.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .backend_qt5 import QtCore
  File "C:\Users\ewasn\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt5.py", line 27, in <module>
    import matplotlib.backends.qt_editor.figureoptions as figureoptions
  File "C:\Users\ewasn\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\qt_editor\figureoptions.py", line 17, in <module>
    import matplotlib.backends.qt_editor.formlayout as formlayout
  File "C:\Users\ewasn\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\qt_editor\formlayout.py", line 58, in <module>
    from matplotlib.backends.qt_compat import QtGui, QtWidgets, QtCore
  File "C:\Users\ewasn\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\qt_compat.py", line 127, in <module>
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
RuntimeError: the sip module implements API v11.0 to v11.2 but the PyQt5.QtCore module requires API v11.3
```

Comment: Is `sip` up to date?

Comment: Facing same problem with `matplotlib`

Comment: I'm facing this issue with PyQt5:
"the sip module implements API v11.0 to v11.2 but the PyQt5.QtWidgets module requires API v11.3"
pip lists sip 4.18, but using a python interpreter I get 4.16.9, and using CMD I get 4.16.8. Related answers were about linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this issue by uninstalling and reinstalling `sip` using `pip`.

```
pip uninstall sip
pip install sip
```

Just doing the upgrade might have work as well, but I got an error during it because the file was in use.

Doing the equivalent in Anaconda might solve the issue.

Comment: It's better to use `pip install sip -U`.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error with pycharm and pyqt4 ... for me was the solution:

The **python version** (in my case python 3.4) **and** the **pyqt4 version have to match**...
So I insalled *python-3.4.4.msi* and after this *PyQt4-4.11.4-gpl-Py3.4-Qt4.8.-x32.exe*

Now it works