# Why can't I covert my .ui file to .py?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtcore

I created a GUI in QT Designer and am trying to convert it from a .ui to a .py file. I have looked at other questions on here, but none have been helpful. I was able to do this without a problem not long ago, but now I am receiving this error:

> RuntimeError: the sip module implements API v12.0 but the PyQt5.QtCore
>   module requires API v12.1

I don't know what to do. If someone could please help it would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried to update sip and PyQt5 and neither have helped me. I have even uninstalled PyQt5 and reinstalled it.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40053422/the-sip-module-implements-api-v11-0-to-v11-2-but-the-pyqt5-qtcore-module-require

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [pyuic4](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/designer.html) for Qt4 and [pyuic5](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html#pyuic5) for Qt5

For sip, do this:

```
pip uninstall sip
pip install sip
```

You can see the post [The sip module implements API v11.0 to v11.2 but the PyQt5.QtCore module requires API v11.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40053422/the-sip-module-implements-api-v11-0-to-v11-2-but-the-pyqt5-qtcore-module-require)

Comment: Thank you very much. That worked for me. I must have missed the other post somehow I guess.